# Android graphics stack

Tags: android, opengl-es

I found some information about graphic stack android and saw this picture:
[image]

But I cannot understood why there was twice OpenGL was used? Is it possible to use openGl only one time after SurfaceFlinger? And after what in this picture does EGL library execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGLES can be used for drawing both 2D and 3D shapes in current systems. In the picture you are showing, in the application stack, GL can be used to render objects by the application. Say, this output goes to a buffer "B". There can be many such applications, so they all create buffers, say B1, B2, B3. Now, there needs to be some framework, that is responsible for deciding which of these buffers gets shown on the display screen, or what combination of buffers gets shown. This is popularly called as "compositor". In the compositor, GL is again used to show content on to display.

So, GL can be used in both applications and compositors, which is what is shown in the stack above.

*EGL is an API* (from Khronos, like OpenGL, OpenGLES) for interfacing to the window system, in this case the Android window system. It creates the buffers B1, B2 etc, into which applications can draw, and also the final display buffers.

So, EGL creates/manages buffers/display, GL is a platform independent API that is responsible for 2D/3D drawing. Hope this helps.